# Law in Japan prohibiting (or just not authorizing?) fines "on people who refuse to stay home"?

Tags: covid-19, japan, fines, public-health

France24 [writes](https://www.france24.com/en/asia-pacific/20200429-focus-amid-rise-in-cases-japan-rethinks-carefree-attitude-to-covid-19) about Covid-19 handling in Japan:

> Unlike in other countries, Japanese authorities are not allowed by law to impose fines or other penalties on people who refuse to stay home. That relaxed approach is partly down to bitter memories of World War II.

What law is this referring to? And was it really adopted in some way relating to WWII (restrictions)? Or am I misunderstanding this (rather unclear) passage? Is it simply talking about a lack of a law authorizing such measures?